# Rails 3.1 sortable nested set with jquery and two models

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-sortable

Here is my issue, I hope someone can point me in the right direction.  I am wanting to utilize drag and drop to create a dynamic catering/restaurant menu.  I would like to create a view that I can add Sections and then add MenuItems to that section (and possible subsections).  I understand fairly easily how I can accomplish this with one model,  but I would like to keep sections and menu items in separate models.  How would I go about setting up the sortable nested set gem  to use dual models?  Should I rethink and use one model?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if you use one model.

The menu item approach seems to be nice. You can write active_record callbacks to add and remove sections/catering/restaurant to and from the menu items model.

GUI for a nested_set gem

https://github.com/the-teacher/the_sortable_tree